# Numpy array masking(Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

I would like to ask a question with numpy array masking.

For instance given the array below:

```
 a b
 1 2
 3 4
 5 6
 6 5
```

I have another array which is

```
 a b
 1 2
 3 4
```

I want to compare two arrays and find the index numbers of second array in the first array.

For instance, the solution should be `index=[0,1]`

I have tried with

```
 np.where np.where(~(np.abs(a - b[:,None]).sum(-1)==0).any(0))
```

but does not give me the final result

thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Please, include methods you've tried and what is wrong with them.

Comment: Can you please provide how you defined the array (the code)?

Comment: it is a data set and defined as x=x.to_numpy()

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on [`Broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), where `ar1` and `ar2` are the two arrays, respectively:

```
np.nonzero(np.any(np.all(ar1 == ar2[:,None], axis=2), axis=0))[0]
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[6,5]])
b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

np.where(np.all(a == b[:,None], axis=2))[1] # np.array([0,1])
```